# Usage of "Make easier", together or apart?

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Are the following sentences all equivalent and valid? which is more fluent?

> - As is shown later, these changes **makes it easier** to create queries in XQuery syntax.
> - As is shown later, these changes **makes easier** creating queries in XQuery syntax.
> - As is shown later, these changes **makes** creating queries in XQuery syntax **easier**.

Comment: @Usernew: In what sense are these duplicates? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @NathanTuggy :) It was for another question, my bad. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 3 are equivalent in terms of meaning, regularity and as you put it "fluency".

2 is incorrect. The phrase `to make [something] [comparative adjective]` needs the `[something]`. Since you omitted `it`, the sentence is wrong.

You should however, use "make" instead of "makes" as `changes` is third person plural.

I'd also modify your first clause. Either remove "is" or add a pronoun.

> As shown later...
>
> As it is shown later...

If this is a document, replace "later" with "below"

> As shown below...

I'd go for the last option.